# Cannot get variable from Java Servlet

Tags: java, variables, servlets

I have an html form that asks user details for a curriculum vitae:

```
<form action = "processdetails.html" method = "post">
    <table>
        <tr><td style = "font-weight: bold">Personal Details:</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "applicant"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile No.:</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "mobile"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E-mail:</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "email"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input style = "width: 150px" type = "submit" value = "Generate CV"/>
</form>
```

After clicking "Generate CV" button, it goes to a Servlet that displays the entered details:

```
@WebServlet("/processdetails.html")
public class ProcessDetailsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String applicantName = "";
    String mobileNo = "";
    String emailAdd = "";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        if(request.getParameter("applicant") != null) {
            applicantName = request.getParameter("applicant");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("mobile") != null) {
            mobileNo = request.getParameter("mobile");          
        }

        if(request.getParameter("email") != null) {
            emailAdd = request.getParameter("email");           
        }

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // other necessary html/css here

        out.print("<form action = 'generatepdf.html' method = 'post'>");
        out.print("<table>");
        out.print("<tr><td style = 'font-weight: bold'>Personal Details:</td></tr>");
        out.print("<tr>");
        out.print("<td>Name:</td>");
        out.print("<td>" + applicantName + "</td>");
        out.print("</tr>");
        out.print("<tr>");
        out.print("<td>Mobile No.:</td>");
        out.print("<td>" + mobileNo + "</td>");
        out.print("</tr>");
        out.print("<tr>");
        out.print("<td>E-mail:</td>");
        out.print("<td>" + emailAdd + "</td>");
        out.print("</tr>");
        out.print("</table>");      
        out.print("<br/>");
        out.print("<input style = 'width: 150px' type = 'submit' value = 'Generate PDF'/>");
        out.print("</form>");

        // other html

        out.close();
    }
}
```

After clicking the "Generate PDF" button, it jumps to another Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/generatepdf.html")
public class GeneratePdfServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        generatePdf();
    }

    protected void generatePdf() {
        System.out.println("This is generatePdf().");

        ProcessDetailsServlet pds = new ProcessDetailsServlet();
        System.out.println("Name: " + pds.applicantName);       
    }
}
```

To check if `generatePdf()` is getting the details, I printed it to console.
However, `applicantName` is not being printed:
[image: no_name]
Why is `applicantName` not being accessed?

Comment: you would run into thread synchronization issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you click on 'Generate CV', your form gets submitted to `ProcessDetailsServlet`
2. `ProcessDetailsServlet` displays result
3. When you click on 'Generate PDF' you again submit to `GeneratePdfServlet`.

Well, basically you will not get any of the user details to the `GeneratePdfServlet` because you are not submitting any value to the `GeneratePdfServlet` when you click on 'Generate PDF'.

User data will not persist for the next request until you manage to save it in a `HttpSession` or some place safe.

Your alternative (if you do not want to use `HttpSession`) is, you can generate a form using `ProcessDetailsServlet` using uneditable input fields instead of table. So next time user clicks on 'Generate PDF', you can resubmit their data and get it in servlet to generate a PDF.

Edit:
Only input fields are submitted in form. So table values don't reach the Servlet.

Comment: These are very well explained points, thank you very much. As we have not discussed `HttpSession` (or anything else aside from `doGet()` and `doPost()`), I will proceed with the suggested workaround of uneditable forms. I think I understand what you mean. Thanks again!

Comment: Their example wouldn't work even if they did submit data in their POST to `/generatepdf.html`. That is not the root cause.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Do you mean the undeditable input fields will not work?

Comment: @ohtph I mean that even if you added `<input>` elements to that form and submit them, your example still wouldn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Could you explain why would `<input>` elements in form not work for a second resubmit, if the developer handles the data getting resubmitted on the `GeneratePdfServlet` ?

Comment: @SharadTank That's the thing, they aren't handling that resubmitted data.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes. Data needs to be refetched from the second request and then used. This 'Data' will only be posted with the form if it is in the input fields.

Comment: ohtph, just let us know if you finally got what I and @SotiriosDelimanolis explained and got your example working. :)

Comment: @SharadTank @SotiriosDelimanolis For now, I just deleted the `GeneratePdfServlet` and put the `generatePdf()` method inside `ProcessDetailsServlet` ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JUGugUU2)). I did not realize I was going into a more advanced lesson when I thought of the idea. But thanks everyone for your insights, they will be very helpful as I progress in our JEE class.

Answer (score 1):

The Servlet container creates a single instance of your `Servlet` implementation(s), in this case, one for `ProcessDetailsServlet` and one for `GeneratePdfServlet`. The servlet container uses these single instances to handle all requests.

When your client sends a POST request to `/processdetails.html`, the container will find the `ProcessDetailsServlet` instance and invoke its `doPost(..)` method (actually its `service(..)` method but that invokes `doPost(..)`). Your `ProcessDetailsServlet` has an instance field

```
String applicantName = "";
```

which you set to

```
applicantName = request.getParameter("applicant");
```

and then produce a response. When the client submits the other form to `/generatepdf.html`, the servlet container finds the `GeneratePdfServlet` instance and invokes its `doPost()` method and then you do this

```
ProcessDetailsServlet pds = new ProcessDetailsServlet();
System.out.println("Name: " + pds.applicantName);
```

You're creating a complete **new** and **unrelated** `ProcessDetailsServlet` instance with its own `applicantName` field that is initialized to `""`. It has absolutely no relation to the other field you set previously, it's a different object!

Comment: Hi, indeed you get what I was trying to do, but as you correctly stated, my code is not doing what I planned it to. Would you kindly post a snippet on what must be done instead?

Comment: @ohtph I won't post code but I will tell what you can do. Extract those 3 fields into a POJO class. Create an instance and set its fields in the `ProcessDetailsServlet`. Then store in the instance in the `HttpSession`. In your `GeneratePdfServlet`, retrieve the instance from the `HttpSession` and you will have access to its fields.

Comment: It seems this would really require `HttpSession`, which we have not discussed as of yet or any persistence of data from servlet to servlet. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ohtph An alternative is to put `hidden` `<input>` elements in the second form and submit them. In your `GeneratePdfServlet` you would re-retrieve them.

Answer (score -2):

I would think it would go something like this...

```
ProcessDetailsServlet pds = new ProcessDetailsServlet();
System.out.println("Name: " + pds. + applicantName);
```